# Horizontally scrolling a PDF without going back to previous webpage in Safari

Tags: macbook-pro, safari

I am having frequently the following problem: I click on a click to open a PDF in Safari; I zoom into that PDF; I need to pan left on the PDF, and instead of using my arrow keys I naturally try to scroll with my mouse pad; Safari then interprets this as me scrolling back to the previous webpage, and instead of panning the document horizontally I am taken back to the page I got to the PDF from. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the **Apple Logo** on the top left of the screen, click **System Preferences** > **Trackpad** > **More Gestures** > **Swipe Between Pages**. Here, you can customize the settings for the feature that you are referring to. I personally turned this setting off because it causes the issue you mentioned. However, if you would like to keep this feature on, you should choose the "3 Finger Swipe" option so that you are still able to move left and right on a pdf.